# mongodb: storing a hierarchical tree structure?

Tags: java, mongodb

on the mongodb, how would I go about storing a hierarchical tree data in which each node contains a Java object containing it's own set of string variables and objects?

If there were no children, it would straight forward. but how would you store a child node DBobject as a field on the mongodb?

for example on a Jtree, if a user clicks and selects delete on a specific node, there should be some unique identifier that would correspond.

p.s. can I create a database for each user and let mongodb authenticate the user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kim,
   You should check out this mongodb article [Trees in mongodb](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/data-models-tree-structures/). It might give you some lead.

Comment: fixed @kaybee99

Answer (score 1):

The document model is JSon so that is a tree structure in itself.  You also have option of embedded (arbitrary) links between docs; naturally you can compose a directed graph of documents linking to one another.

Comment: do you mean to serialize the tree data into JSON and store this? how would I access individual child nodes in the document?

Comment: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating+Data+in+Mongo#UpdatingDatainMongo-EmbeddingDocumentsDirectlyinDocuments