# MongoDB - helps with cascading hierarchies?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

It becomes more and more common where in my app I have to maintain a cascading tree structure.

The tree defines the permissions and any objects associated with it. That cascade down, so that changing one, modifies (or derives the data for) the whole subtree.

With ActiveRecord and SQL it is pretty complicated to deal with. One option is to denormalise it and use "paths": "root/child1/child2" and SQL `like`-s to work with it.

But I just start wondering if the database itself is right for this and maybe consider using MongoDB.

There are other parts that might not be a good fir for using with MongoDB: transactions (during payments, reservations).

So my question is, would switching to MongoDB help to solve the "cascading hierarchy" problem?

Comment: It may be duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448415/mongodb-storing-a-hierarchical-tree-structure

Comment: Thanks. The link there provides a good overview of working with trees in MongoDB. But don't think it's duplicate and leans me to answer my questions with "Yes".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So my question is, would switching to MongoDB help to solve the "cascading hierarchy" problem?

The primary benefit is honestly the ability to store the entire hierarchy in one document. Then you can basically "annotate" portions of the document with their permissions. Obviously, such "annotations" don't actually exist, they would just be fields in the document, so this will involve you building a layer for all of this.

So in theory, it's quite possible to do what you want, but it does have some limitations.

In particular, when MongoDB queries a document, it queries the whole document. If your whole hierarchy fits in a single document then you get the whole hierarchy with one query. If not, then you start devolving back to the SQL method of handling this.